# Board and Card Games mentioned on the SE podcast #6. Does anyone know what they were talking about?

Tags: discussion

Jeff and Joel mentioned the Board and Card Games stack exchange site several times in the new [SE podcast (#6)](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/se-podcast-06/) (first mention at 51:30).

The site came up because they were talking about chaos money and their new evangelism team; evidently there is a question on our meta that worked as a good example of what this new team would be doing, but I couldn't tell what question they were talking about. Does anyone know?

One topic seemed to be about introducing new games to the community and another perhaps about meet-ups, but I'm not sure (hence this question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I was thinking of RPG:

https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/978/buying-the-community-books-to-generate-questions

But a similar initiative could work well here, too, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to listen to the podcast yet.  Are you sure it was B&CG and not Gaming?

It really sounds like what they are doing [over there](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/community-promotion-sponsorship-new-game-releases-for-community-members).

Comment: I just entered the time hack. Jeff specifically mentions board games, and that the proposal was to get new board games into the hands of members, but looking at your link it's possible he was talking about the (computer) gaming site and got it confused with this one, although only a couple of minutes later Joel mentioned that the gaming site had a similar idea to the board game site (i.e. getting games into the hands of members, so I think that proposal is the one you linked to.